# Redirect STDERR to a file from Perl in Linux

Tags: linux, perl, stderr

So, I was trying to catch the error messages from running some basic Linux command, using Perl. For example, I try to catch the `STDERR` when running the `ldd` command:

```
# The stderr_file already exists
my $cmd = "ldd $file 2>$stderr_file";
my $output = `$cmd`;
```

But, even if the output of the `ldd` command does contain error messages such as `ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for`, it won't print them in to the `$stderr_file`, and I wonder why.

Then I tried to run the command myself: `ldd /some/path/to/file 2>./error.log` and it failed with: `ldd: ./2: No such file or directory`.

I suspect that the reason is due to the fact my Linux uses `Tcsh` because if I switch to `Bash`, the command works.

How should I approach this issue and solve it?

Also, I read some previous thread but didn't find any related thread or method to solve it.

Comment: Backticks tend to run `/bin/sh` in Linux, not `tcsh`. Check `perl -MConfig -wle 'print $Config{sh}'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When interpolating strings into shell commands that are intended to be single arguments, you should always use [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote) to avoid bugs where the shell parses unintended metacharacters in your strings (including space characters). It only implements bourne shell quoting though, so it may not be compatible with tcsh either - but Perl is usually configured to use /bin/sh, which should be bourne shell compatible.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use String::ShellQuote;
my $cmd = 'ldd ' . shell_quote($file) . ' 2>' . shell_quote($stderr_file);
```

As an alternative, you can avoid the shell entirely by using the list form of system() and redirecting STDERR within Perl. [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) makes this easy.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Capture::Tiny 'capture';
use Path::Tiny;
my ($out, $err, $exit_code) = capture { system 'ldd', $file };
# error checking for system() call here
path($stderr_file)->spew_raw($err);
```

(Path::Tiny is just an example, you can also use File::Slurper or open the file and write to it yourself with appropriate error checking.)

The core module [IPC::Open3](https://perldoc.pl/IPC::Open3) can also be used to capture STDERR separately and avoid the shell, somewhat more manually.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Open3;
use Symbol 'gensym';
my $pid = open3 undef, my $stdout, my $stderr = gensym, 'ldd', $file;
my ($out, $err);
{
  local $/;
  $out = readline $stdout;
  $err = readline $stderr;
}
waitpid $pid, 0;
my $exit_code = $? >> 8;
```

This can run into deadlocks if the process outputs a sufficient amount to STDERR. I highly recommend making use of Capture::Tiny instead as above, or [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) or [IPC::Run3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3) for more flexibility.

Comment: So as I understand, there is no way to do it without any additional modules?

Comment: @TTaJTa4 It is of course possible (by doing the same things Capture::Tiny does), but it is rather dirty. I will add an example using IPC::Open3, which is a core module but still more ugly than using Capture::Tiny.

Comment: I think I'll try the modules, but can you add an example which shows how to do it without any (for the sake of education :) )? Even without the core module

Comment: @TTaJTa4 I cannot see a point to reimplementing this without making use of the core modules you have available, but the source code of Capture::Tiny and IPC::Open3 are freely available.

Comment: Learnt alot from you to! I tried to run: `cmd = "ldd ".shell_quote($file).' 2>'.shell_quote($stderr_file);` and then ``$cmd;`` but it does not work (does not print to the `STDERR`). why?

Comment: @TTaJTa4 Does bypassing the shell work? There are any number of reasons that command would not successfully write to that file, such as misidentifying the file relative to your current directory, or a permissions issue.

Comment: Sorry for the long comment section. does `2>` overrides the previous content of the file? this commend was executed in a loop. So maybe this is the issue?

Comment: @TTaJTa4 Yes, this could definitely be the problem - `>` is a clobbering operator, so it will clear the file immediately, and then append output. Try `>>` to append without clobbering.

Comment: Your IPC::Open3 code is buggy. It will deadlock if the child outputs a sufficient amount to its STDERR. Use IPC::Run or IPC::Run3 instead.

Comment: @ikegami I agree. Unfortunately neither of those are core either, so you might as well use the Capture::Tiny solution in this case.